# Problem with Mootools Ajax request and submitting a form

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, mootools

I have a table with content  comming  from a  database. Now i tryed to realize a  way  to (a) delete rows from the table (b) edit the content of the row "on the fly".  (a) is working perfectly (b) makes my head smoking!

Here is the complete Mootools Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

var eDit = $('edit_hide');
eDit.slide('hide'); 

var del = new Request.HTML(
{
    url: 'fuss_response.php',
    encoding: 'utf-8',
    update: eDit,
    onComplete: function(response)
    {
    eDit.slide('in');
    }
});

$$('input.delete').addEvent( 'click', function(e){
      e.stop();
    var aID = 'delete_', bID = '';
    var deleteID = this.getProperty('id').replace(aID,bID); 
      new MooDialog.Confirm('Soll der Termin gelöscht werden?', function(){
        del.send({data : "id=" + deleteID}); 
      }, function(){
      new MooDialog.Alert('Schon Konfuzius hat gesagt: Erst denken dann handeln!');
      });  
    });

var edit = new Request.HTML(
{
    url: 'fuss_response_edit.php',
    update: eDit,
    encoding: 'utf-8',
    onComplete: function(response)
    {
    $('sst').addEvent( 'click', function(e){
      e.stop();
    safe.send();
    });
    }
});

var safe = new Request.HTML(
{
    url: 'termin_safe.php',
    encoding: 'utf-8',
    update: eDit,
    onComplete: function(response)
    {

    }
});

$$('input.edit').addEvent( 'click', function(e){
      e.stop();
    var aID = 'edit_', bID = '';
    var editID = this.getProperty('id').replace(aID,bID); 
      edit.send({data : "id=" + editID});
      $('edit_hide').slide('toggle');
    });

});
</script>
```

Here the PHP Part that makes the Edit Form:

```
<?php

$cKey = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

$request = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fusspflege WHERE ID = '".$cKey."'");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($request))
    {
    $id = $row->ID;
    $name = $row->name;
    $vor = $row->vorname;
    $ort = $row->ort;
    $tel = $row->telefon;
    $mail = $row->email;
    }
echo '<form id="termin_edit" method="post" action="">';
echo '<div><label>Name:</label><input type="text" id="nns" name="name" value="'.$name.'"></div>';
echo '<div><label>Vorname:</label><input type="text" id="nvs" name="vorname" value="'.$vor.'"></div>';
echo '<div><label>Ort:</label><input type="text" id="nos" name="ort" value="'.$ort.'"></div>';
echo '<div><label>Telefon:</label><input type="text" id="nts" name="telefon" value="'.$tel.'"></div>';
echo '<div><label>eMail:</label><input type="text" id="nms" name="email" value="'.$mail.'"></div>';
echo '<input name="id" type="hidden" id="ids" value="'.$id.'"/>';
echo '<input type="button" id="sst" value="Speichern">';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

And last the Code of the termin_safe.php

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$na = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$vn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vorname']);
$ort = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ort']);
$tel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telefon']);
$em = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);  
$score = mysql_query("UPDATE fuspflege SET name = '".$na."', vorname = '".$vn."', ort = '".$ort."', telefon = '".$tel."', email = '".$em."' WHERE ID = '".$id."'");
```

As far as i can see the request does work but the data is not updated! i guess  somethings  wrong with the things posted
For any suggestions i will be gladly happy!

PS after  some  comments:   I see  the problem in this  part:

```
var edit = new Request.HTML(
{
    url: 'fuss_response_edit.php',
    update: eDit,
    encoding: 'utf-8',
    onComplete: function(response)
    {
    $('sst').addEvent( 'click', function(e){
      e.stop();
    safe.send();
    });
    }
});
```

The "Edit" request opens  the form with the prefilled input fields and then attaches a click event to the submit button which should call a new  request when clicked.
This  third  request i fail to pass  the  data of the  input  fields.  i tried to get the  value of  each field  like this:

```
var name = $('nns').getProperty('value');
```

and pass  it this way

```
.send({data : "name=" + name});
```

did not work so far

PPS:
  as  requested  the  code  that makes  the html  from main site

```
<?php  $request = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fusspflege");
  echo '<form id="fusspflege" method="post" action="">';
  echo '<table class="fuss_admin">';
  echo '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Vorname</th><th>Ort</th><th>Telefon</th><th>eMail</th><th>Uhrzeit</th><th>Datum</th><th></th><th></th></tr>';
  echo '<tr><td colspan=8 id="upd"></td></tr>';
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($request))
    {
    $id = $row->ID;
    $name = $row->name;
    $vor = $row->vorname;
    $ort = $row->ort;
    $tel = $row->telefon;
    $mail = $row->email;
    $dat = $row->datum;
    $uhr = $row->uhrzeit;

    echo '<tr><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$vor.'</td><td>'.$ort.'</td><td>'.$tel.'</td><td>'.$mail.'</td><td>'.$uhr.'</td><td>'.$dat.'</td>';
    echo '<td><input id="delete_'.$id.'" class="delete" type="button" value="X"></td>';
    echo '<td><input id="edit_'.$id.'" class="edit" type="button" value="?"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
  echo '</table>';
  echo '</form>';
  echo '<div id="edit_hide"></div>';
?>
```

UPDATE:

```
       <form action="" method="post" id="termin_edit">
    <div>
        <label>
            Name:
        </label>
        <input type="text" value="NAME" name="name" id="nns">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            Vorname:
        </label>
        <input type="text" value="Marianne" name="vorname" id="nvs">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            Ort:
        </label>
        <input type="text" value="MArkt Wald" name="ort" id="nos">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            Telefon:
        </label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="telefon" id="nts">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            eMail:
        </label>
        <input type="text" value="info@rudolfapotheke.de" name="email" id="nms">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" value="115" id="ids" name="id">
    <input type="button" value="Speichern" id="sst">
</form>
```

Comment: need to put the echo statements in the while loop if you want to ech out all the $rows data

Comment: not  really  as  it outputs only  one dataset ( the one that matches  the  id posted)  :)   this only  makes  a  prefilled  form that opens when i click the  edit  button on main page. on a second stage i want to be  able to alter  the  content  now  and  then send it  back to database. and here is my problem!  the sending  and  updating  doesnt work

Comment: you don't need a while loop there if it's only one row

Comment: add a debugger for query after you do `if (!$score) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}`

Comment: does the request  get  the  data  from the  input  fields  or  do i need  to specify the data beeing  send ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

This is the mootools script based on the form you gave me that should work with your html:

```
$('sst').addEvent('click', function(event) {
    var data;
    event.stop();
    var myInputEl = $$('#termin_edit input');
    for(var i=0; i<myInputEl.length; i++){
        if(i == 0)
            data = myInputEl[i].name + "=" + myInputEl[i].value;
        else
            data += "&" + myInputEl[i].name + "=" + myInputEl[i].value;
    }
    myRequest.send(data);
});
```

Also add alert to your Request call back for the edit just to test if the ajax worked:

```
    onSuccess: function(responseText) {
        alert("done! " + responseText);
    },
    onFailure: function() {
        alert("failed");
    }
```

On the php side create a new PHP file and put the following in it and have ajax target it:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

The Ajax should return the $_POST array in the alert box.

Comment: ok  that i need  to specify  the  data  is clear - i did  that in the  first  2 requests. but this last one seems  to not be able  to  access  the  data from the  fields and i dont know  why

Comment: @Arwed isolate the ajax first and test to see if the correct data are passed in first before you debug the php side.  let me know once you get the ajax to work and i'll help you tackle the php side.

Comment: the  echo  is  empty   so  no  data  is passed.  i cleaned  up  the  javascript  code  a  bit  and  post  again  in  my origin question

Comment: @Arwed the best way to approach these issue is to post a sample data (your html) and first track down the ajax side and make sure that works first. than tackle server mysql injection side.

Comment: i posted  the php  code  that makes  the html....  also note  the update  i made on  the  javascript  code

Comment: @kjy112  where  does  mootools  get  the variables  u want  to send  with :    **edit.send({data : "id=" + editID + "&name=" + editName + "&vorname=" + vorname + "&ort=" + ort + "&telefon=" + telefon + "&email=" + email});**

Comment: @Arwed you have to set them from your form. which is in your html that you generated w/ your php code.

Comment: Go ahead and post a snippet of your html code (your edit form) else i would just be guessing what you have, and can't really help you debug your problems.

Comment: i can read  out   the  value of  the  form   with    var ort = $('nos').getProperty('value');   and  then  instead of  send  it  i  made  a  try  to write  it  to  the  page  and  it  works.  so i can narrow it down  to  the  request  cant  send  what  i give  him

Comment: @kjy112  excellent job!  can´t  express  how you safed  my day!  thank you very much! it worked

Comment: @Arwed =D took awhile but glad it works out also if you have further question you shoudl try #mootools on IRC freenode